# TryFindByPrimaryKey in Castle ActiveRecord

Tags: c#, castle-activerecord

How do I search for a record by primary key, but return null if it doesn't exist?

```
public static T FindByPrimaryKeyOrDefault(object id)
{
  try
  {
    return ActiveRecordMediator<T>.FindByPrimaryKey(id);
  }
  catch (NotFoundException)
  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ActiveRecordMediator<T>.FindByPrimaryKey(id, false);
```

I'll copy questions like these to the [ActiveRecord wiki](http://using.castleproject.org/display/AR/FAQ).